# Why the funtion answer is incorrect

Tags: mysql

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION get_ascii_sum (word VARCHAR ( 55 )) 
    RETURNS INT ( 11 ) 
    BEGIN
    DECLARE count_word INT DEFAULT LENGTH( word );
    DECLARE index_count INT DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE alphabet_abc VARCHAR ( 55 ) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE sum_ascii INT DEFAULT 0;
    REPEAT
        SET alphabet_abc = SUBSTRING( word FROM index_count FOR 1 );
        SET sum_ascii =sum_ascii + ASCII( alphabet_abc );
        SET index_count = index_count + 1;
    UNTIL index_count <= count_word 
    END REPEAT;
    RETURN sum_ascii;
END //
```

The above code means I want to get the sum of the ASCII value of the word that you gave. When I input 'abc' but it always returns 97.

Answer (score 1):

You might be mixing two different concepts in your mind, the `do...while` vs `repeat...until`. The main difference, apart from the syntax, is that `REPEAT` will run at least once.

You can fix your code by doing either...

```sql
WHILE index_count <= word_count DO
   /* do something */
END WHILE;
```

or ...

```sql
REPEAT
  /* do something */
UNTIL index_count > word_count
END REPEAT;
```

Reading material:

- https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure/mysql-repeat-loop/
- https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure/mysql-while-loop/